# How to scare people when they touch my laptop screen?

Tags: user, laptop-display, fingerprint

I would like to discourage people from touching my screen.

I have a touch screen laptop, and sometimes people come to explain stuff to me, and point out with their fingers and touch my screen. I would like, when someone touches the screen, to trigger some kind of startling action; for example, it becomes RED and some kind of loud scary sound plays.

Is there a way to do something like this?

[image: a monster eating fingers]

Note: I use Fedora.

Comment: I'm not sure it's on-topic here, it sounds more like a [softwarerecs.se], but it's a great and funny idea 

Comment: Capture an input event from the touchscreen and use that as the trigger.

Comment: @arieljannai, I read for twice [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask) before post the question. Also, thanks about your comment.

Comment: @danihp So maybe I'm mistaken  Good luck!

Comment: I think an app like that would probably get people to touch your screen MORE !! that monster is hilarious UPVOTE

Comment: I think PeterH is right, people will touch it more for the entertainment.  What you really need is a way to give them an electrical jolt when their finger touches the screen.  :-)

Comment: What research have you done regarding this? Have you looked into capturing triggers on the touch screen?

Comment: @fixer1234, thanks a lot about to improve my syntax and language on question .